# How to access camera on an AWS EC2 instance(g4dn.xlarge) for my FastAPI backend in the webapp?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, gpu, fastapi, webcam

I built a webapp with ReactJs as front end and FastAPI as backend. With the below mentioned FastAPI code I was able to access to webcam and capture users facial expressions and run some ML algo on the recorded video. The code was working fine in my local machine on Mac.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

    with mp_holistic.Holistic(
        min_detection_confidence=0.5,
        min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
        while cap.isOpened() and not stop_event.is_set():
            success, image = cap.read()
            if not success:
                continue
            
            image.flags.writeable = False
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            results = holistic.process(image)

            
            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            
            
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                image,
                results.face_landmarks,
                mp_holistic.FACEMESH_CONTOURS,
                landmark_drawing_spec=None,
                connection_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
                .get_default_face_mesh_contours_style())
            
            
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                image,
                results.right_hand_landmarks,
                mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
            
            
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                image,
                results.left_hand_landmarks,
                mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
            
            
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                image,
                results.pose_landmarks,
                mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                landmark_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles
                .get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
            
            if(results.face_landmarks == None):
                number_of_frames_with_no_face += 1
            else:
                number_of_frames_with_face += 1
                number_of_frames_with_face_periodic += 1
            
            if(results.pose_landmarks == None):
                number_of_frames_with_no_shoulders += 1
            else:
                number_of_frames_with_shoulders += 1
                number_of_frames_with_shoulders_periodic += 1

            if(results.left_hand_landmarks == None):
                
                number_of_frames_with_no_left_hand += 1
                number_of_frames_with_no_left_hand_periodic +=1
            else:
                
                number_of_frames_with_left_hand += 1 
                number_of_frames_with_left_hand_periodic += 1
                
                if(number_of_frames_with_left_hand == 1):
                    left_constant_x = results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x
                    left_constant_y = results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y
                    
                else:
                    if(abs(left_constant_x - results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x) > 0.10 or abs(left_constant_y - results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y) > 0.10):
                        left_constant_x = results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x
                        left_constant_y = results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y
                        left_hand_moved += 1
                

            if(results.right_hand_landmarks == None):
                
                number_of_frames_with_no_right_hand += 1
                number_of_frames_with_no_right_hand_periodic += 1
            else:
                
                number_of_frames_with_right_hand += 1 
                number_of_frames_with_right_hand_periodic += 1

                if(number_of_frames_with_right_hand == 1):
                    right_constant_x = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x
                    right_constant_y = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y
                else:
                    if(abs(right_constant_x - results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x) > 0.10 or abs(right_constant_y - results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y) > 0.10):
                        right_constant_x = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x
                        right_constant_y = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y
                        right_hand_moved += 1

                if(number_of_frames_with_right_hand_periodic == 1):
                    right_constant_x_periodic = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x
                    right_constant_y_periodic = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y
                else:
                    if(abs(right_constant_x_periodic - results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x) > 0.10 or abs(right_constant_y_periodic - results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y) > 0.10):
                        right_constant_x_periodic = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].x
                        right_constant_y_periodic = results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark[0].y
                        right_hand_moved_periodic += 1

            await asyncio.sleep(0.02)
        
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now when I am running the same code on an EC2 Ubuntu instance(Instance type - g4dn.xlarge as I was told that it is required for GPU), I am getting the below error.

```
Aug 12 17:38:45 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | INFO: - "GET /analysis/start?param=presentation&user_id=54 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Aug 12 17:38:45 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | [ WARN:0@132.006] global cap_v4l.cpp:982 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
Aug 12 17:38:45 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | [ERROR:0@132.006] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
Aug 12 17:38:46 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Aug 12 17:38:46 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | [ WARN:0@132.241] global cap_v4l.cpp:982 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
Aug 12 17:38:46 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | [ERROR:0@132.241] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
Aug 12 17:38:46 ip docker[769]: back_end-web-1  | ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
```

When I checked the machine with `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` command, I got the response as `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.`.

Questions -

1. Would The logic(of accessing webcam of user using webapp" even work on an AWS cloud?
2. If yes, then what configuration changes do I need to make so that the backend can access user's webcam and start analysis?

Comment: There is no web camera attached to a Amazon EC2 instance. And if it were, it wouldn't be the _users web camera_. You'll have to implement the web camera interface in your frontend, then send the data to your backend for processing (so the frontend retrieves/fetches the data and submits it to the backend for analysis).

Comment: You cannot do this from the backend, even with _other_ server-side hosting services/platforms, not just AWS. Your FastAPI app (backend) and your React website (frontend) would be running on _different_ machines, and your backend has no access to your users' physical hardware. Your backend is running on some server "in the cloud" and your users will be viewing your website from their own machine. It works on your local because both backend and frontend are on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, this is exactly what I thought. I think I will have to use Websosckets to achieve the result, sending frame-by-frame data to backend from frontend and then do the analysis there.